# How to avoid microservice dependency without slowing down your release process?

Tags: deployment, microservices, devops, software-design, go-cd

How to avoid microservice dependency without slowing down your release process

We are deploying services and its a microservice based project but since we are having many small services going through parallel development we are struggling for deployment.
Example -
Admin build - v1.1.1
this is having dependancy on some other build v.x.x.x

so once build x is not fully tested we can not release admin v1.1.1

is there any solution for it to make deployment process more smooth ?

Answer (score 1):

2 Pointers I can give you are:

1. Always have your API's backwards compatible - this way you lower your dependencies in one version or the other, creating higher isolation.
2. Use feature flags - when you change behaviour you can then deploy the code but it doesn't have to be active at that exact time. Use feature flags to wrap your changes and switch them on when you are ready.

Comment: That's true and thanks for the advice but is there any automated way to control this ? If yes please share the thoughts , it will be helpful